# C++, SFML warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++, sfml

Код:

```
bool Button::isMouseRightClicked(sf::RenderWindow &window){
    if(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x>=button.getPosition().x&&
            sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x<=button.getPosition().x+button.getLocalBounds().width){
        if(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y>=button.getPosition().y&&
                sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y<=button.getPosition().y+button.getLocalBounds().height){
            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Right))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ощибка:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Компиляция:

```
COMPILER = c++
FILES = Window.cpp bin/Button/Button.cpp bin/Fonts/Fonts.cpp
OUTPUT = Test
LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-Window

output:
    ${COMPILER} ${FILES} -o ${OUTPUT} ${LIBS}
```

Comment: Ну? А прочитать нельзя? ... Сообщение говорит о том что, в одном из возможных ветвлений, отсутствует `return type`, когда метод обязан вернуть значение.

Comment: Ну вроде значение возвращаеться

Comment: Во всех случаях? Внимательно смотри код.  Там 2 варианта, при которых не возвращается ничего.

Comment: кароче понял
в конце добавил return 0;
и в компиляции была ощибка: вместо -lsfml-Window должно было быть -lsfml-window